# Desired way of running a web scraping cronjob within a Laravel web app to save data to DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, screen-scraping

Currently working on a new web service that requires me to scrape a site every couple hours to save the data into my MySQL database.

My question is - how should my scraper run?

For now I see a few ways:

1. The cronjob runs a scraping script written in PHP, scrapes the data, and saves the data into a flatfile (i.e. csv), which then I setup a Controller to parse the data and have my Model save the data
2. The cronjob runs a scraping script written in PHP, scrapes the data, and *immediately* saves the data into my DB as each rows of data comes in

Of the two methods above, which one is better? If I am simply talking out of my ass, could you please suggest me a better way to:

1. Scrape the date
2. Save the data to my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two options of saving scrapped data, if I were you, I would go after the second way. The reason is simply that it is easier to manage the scrapped data once they are already in DB -- it would save you the burden of generating and using temporary files.

Saving (appending new data) into a flat file may be faster than inserting into DB. But when time/performance is critical, you can either run your cronjob more frequently or run multiple copies of your cronjob (say, each of them scrapping different websites or different web pages).

Comment: Would the first option or second option have a greater impact on IO performances to the DB? To me it seems the second option would write to the DB every single time a new data row hits (I have around 2k rows of data each time I scrape).

Comment: You can do the following to reduce the impact on DB performance:
1. insert many rows at one time -- instead of one row at one time;
2. using a different DB for storing scrapped data, and then later on synchronizing this DB to the DB that the front-end users is accessing to.

Comment: If I am understanding what you are saying, I should scrape all my data first, store the data into a (or multiple) data structure, then in a multi row query, save the data to the DB. Secondly what do you mean by using two DBs?